# How to retrieve an image on database and display avatar when image is null

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I want to retrieve an image on my database,and I also want to retrieve images even it is null. now what i have on my image folder is an avatar, the avatar is also retrieve when the field is null. and when it is not null the image on the database will retrieve how can I do it ? how can I do it on this statement? thanks

here is my database connection

```
    <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM shopusers");

$id= $_SESSION['id'];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM shopusers WHERE id=$id";
      $results = mysqli_query($con, $query);
      $num=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

?>
```

here is my fetch query

```
 <?php
        $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from shopusers where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
      ?>                    

           <?php 
           if($row == null){
              echo "<div class='avatar'><img src='img/avatar-6.jpg' alt='...' class='img-fluid rounded-circle'></div>";         
           }else{
            echo "<div class='avatar'><img src='users_image/".$row['image']."' alt='...' class='img-fluid rounded-circle'></div>";
           }

           ?>

      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is storing images in the database a must? If not, store it together with avatar (wither user id to differentiate them)

Comment: @Jacob yes storing is a must. but what I need is when the field image is null the avatar should display not like a corrupted image on the image src

Comment: @Jacob , how can i do the syntax of this stament. `if image is found, display avatar else display row image`

Answer (score 1):

1. Storing images in database is not a good idea because your application will require more memory.
2. Since OP mentioned it's a must to store in database, you can output it via data src.

   ```
          <?php 
          if(empty($row['image'])){
             echo "<div class='avatar'><img src='img/avatar-6.jpg' alt='...' class='img-fluid rounded-circle'></div>";         
          }else{
           echo '<div class="avatar"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"' alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></div>';
          }

          ?>

     <?php } ?>
   ```

Comment: Hi ! @Jacob , thanks for your kindness to help me but I want to have this condition but unfortunately i dont know the syntax please help me on this pseudocode `if image is found, display avatar else display row image`

Comment: did you mean 'if image is not found (null), display avatar, else display the $row[image]' data?  I have updated the answer for this condition.